# I/O operations are blocking mysql transactions

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

here we have a x64 Debian Lenny with MySQL 5.1.47 and some InnoDB databases on it. ibdata files and other stuff is on the same file system (ext3). I've noticed, that on some situations there are many processes in MySQL process list which hang on "freeing items" state. This happens when I do the following on shell (file1 and file2 are about 2.5gb)

```
cat file1 file2 >new_file
```

or execute the following SQL statement

```
SELECT 'name' AS col UNION SELECT col FROM db_name.table_name INTO OUTFILE ('/var/xxx/yyy')
```

When one of these two things is running, then I can see many MySQL processes running endless with "freeing items" state (I'm using innotop). When killing this shell process (or SQL statement) then these blocked transactions disappear.

In internet I found some hints to disable InnoDB adaptive hash index and common query cache, but this doesn't help. Is there someone who has the same experience?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've found turning on the deadline i/o scheduler to be of great help keeping our db from starving during hi external load on the file system. Try

```
 echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

And test if the problem becones smaller. (Replace `sda` for the device your db is on)

Comment: /sys/block/cciss!c0d0/queue/scheduler contains it already:
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]

Comment: @user545917 that means cfq is the active one, set it to deadline with `echo deadline > '/sys/block/cciss!c0d0/queue/scheduler'`

Comment: Hi nos, long time has passed, but today it was possible to set this option on our database server, and...tadaaa: it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just stepping back a bit, have you done some basic InnoDB tuning? The MySQL defaults can be pretty limiting.  A good overview:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Answer (score 0):

The interesting is:

- all databases on this server are kept in one InnoDB file (one_file_per_table is disabled)
- we've written a small shell script, inserting 10 rows per second in a new table in a new database on this server
- then we've copied some big files via "cat" (like described above) parallel...
- and: nothing happend, no locks, no endless "freeing items"
- so we've changed the shell script to insert the lines in a new table in the existing database, which causes this problems and copied the files again
- and: the locks are back! huh?
- last try: we've copied the "buggy" database on the server itself into a new database (with full structure and data) and started shell script again
- and: no "freeing items" processes!?

I don't understand this behavior: inserting in the old database let these "freeing items" processes appear, but inserting into a new database (full copy of the old database) is fine?